# If $U = (1, 2)$, $V = (3, -4)$, is the answer to $2U + \frac{1}{2}V$ the vector $(3.5, 2)$? Check my answer.

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic

If $U = (1, 2)$, $V = (3, -4)$, is the answer to $2U + \frac{1}{2}V$ the vector $(3.5, 2)$?

I did the following:

\begin{align*}
U : ( ( 2   * 1   ),  ( 2   *  2 ) ) &= ( 2  ,  4 )\\
V : ( ( 0.5 * 3   ),  ( 0.5 * -4 ) ) &= ( 1.5, -2 )\\
( ( 2   + 1.5 ) + ( 4   + -2 ) ) &= ( 3.5,  2 )
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't want to carry on if I was getting this wrong. Now I know it's right I can go through the rest of this schmexy book. I'm 24 and still don't know simple algebra. #dontblameme :) (in regards to 3d game programming and various vector manipulations and estimations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your final answer is correct, but some of your intermediate steps could be considered wrong (or at least unclear).

First of all, you write

$$U : (2 * 1, 2 * 2) = (2, 4).$$

It's not clear at all what you mean by this. What you have done is calculated $2U$. A much better way of writing this is

$$2U = (2 * 1, 2 * 2) = (2, 4).$$

Likewise, you should write

$$\frac{1}{2}V = (0.5 * 3, 0.5 * (-4)) = (1.5, -2).$$

As for your final line, you haven't indicated what you are doing. You are adding $2U$ and $\frac{1}{2}V$ so you should write

$$2U + \frac{1}{2}V = (2 + 1.5, 4 + (-2)) = (3.5, 2).$$

In summary, I think it would be better to format your answer as follows:

> \begin{align*}
> 2U &= (2 * 1, 2 * 2) = (2, 4)\\
> &\\
> \frac{1}{2}V &= (0.5 * 3, 0.5 * (-4)) = (1.5, -2)\\
> &\\
> 2U + \frac{1}{2}V &= (2 + 1.5, 4 + (-2)) = (3.5, 2).
> \end{align*}

Alternatively, you could do all of the calculations at the same time:

> $$2U + \frac{1}{2}V = (2 * 1, 2 * 2) + (0.5 * 3, 0.5 * (-4)) = (2, 4) + (1.5, -2) = (3.5, 2).$$

---

These comments are less important than the ones made above, but I think still worth pointing out. They are more about style than content.

In is better to use $\cdot$ or $\times$ to denote multiplication rather than $*$.

You shouldn't swap between fractions and decimals unless you have a good reason. As the question involved a fraction, use fractions the whole way through.

With these points in mind, I would present the calculation as follows:

> \begin{align*}
> 2U + \frac{1}{2}V &= 2(1, 2) + \frac{1}{2}(3, -4)\\ 
> &= (2\times 1, 2\times 2) + \left(\frac{1}{2}\times 3, \frac{1}{2}\times (-4)\right)\\ 
> &= (2, 4) + \left(\frac{3}{2}, -2\right)\\ 
> &= \left(\frac{5}{2}, 2\right).
> \end{align*}